# Getting 500 using rest-assured but getting 200 in Postman

Tags: java, rest-assured

In postman, I input URL, POST method, Header (key - `x-api-key` and value), in Body (`listId` and value) and by sending the request getting 200 success response.

[image: postman response]

But using maven project, Java language and rest-assured, I am getting -

> Response status code: 500 &
> Response body: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Here is my code -

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseBody;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class TC001_CacheStatus {
    @Test
    public void CacheStatusCheck() throws IOException {
     
        // Set base URI of the API
        String baseUrl = "https://url.here";

        // Define headers
        String apiKey = "X-ApiKey";
        String apiValue = "value_here";

        // Define form data
        String formDataKey = "listId";
        String listId = "65cd9b8f";

        // Send POST request with headers and form data
        Response response =   RestAssured.given()
                                    .baseUri(baseUrl)
                                    .header("x-api-key", apiKey) 
                                    .multiPart("listId", listId)
                                    .contentType("multipart/form-data")
                                    .post("/endpoint")
                                    .andReturn();


        // Print response
        System.out.println("Response status code: " + response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("Response body: " + response.getBody().asString());

    }
}
```

How can I solve this? Please help.

Comment: Server error 500 can happen because of a variety of different errors on the server side. What does the server side logs say? Does it give any clue as to what may be wrong?

Comment: Besides, you are saying that you use GET in Postman and then it is not likely that you actually submit anything in the body. What happens when you switch to POST in Postman, which is what you are using in your code in the question.

Comment: Postman is potentially defaulting a lot of things (such as headers, forms etc.). You should first start by making sure that everything between Postman and Rest-assured is the same, and if it's the case chances are high that the result will be the same too.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ that's what I am trying to do, I already given what I am doing in Postman, and I am asking for help, where I need to change in the code?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian how can I get the server side logs?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian for POST method in postman, I am getting 200 with success response as well, but I donot know what's wrong in my code? and where do I need to change?

Comment: The problem is because of authorization type was missing, how can I add auth as API Key type?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ 
I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: @DanielBarbarian  I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Well, the obvious difference I can see is that you in Postman are setting a Header called X-ApiKey and in code you are calling it x-api-key. Try changing your code to make sure the header has the same name.

Comment: Note the tag description on [tag:api] which says "DO NOT USE".

Answer (score 0):

Try `response.then().log().ifValidationFails()` to check if post-query is right.

Comment: how can I  add authorization type auth as API Key type Header ?